# How to create 'before insert' trigger that looks at multiple tables

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

I am struggling to understand the format to create an 'insert before' trigger that must meet conditions of other tables.

For example, if I have a table named 'borrowed' that I would like to insert values into but must meet conditions from another table called 'member'. The condition is that MemberStatus = 'regular'. If this condition passes, I will be able to run a 'insert into borrowed' but if the conditions aren't met then it will not be able to pass.

This is how I previously understood the concept but after hours of reading i've become confused. Any help would be appreciated.

```
delimiter //
drop trigger if exists trigger1
//

create trigger trigger1
before insert on borrowed
for each row

begin
if...
end if;
end;
//
```

Comment: Er,, you probably wouldnt insert into the table you're triggering on from within the trigger processing the insert, but feel free to write values into the `new` pseudorows columns to change the values that end up being written to the table... If you just want to check that the values being inserted into Borrowed match something in Member and not do the insert if they don't then you can read the `new` value, look it up in Member (e.g. is the Fee between Member.LowerFee and Member.UpperFee) and if it's not, raise an error to prevent the insert

Comment: In mysql you cannot action(insert/update/delete) the table that fired the trigger in the trigger, you could reverse your logic and abort the insert if the condition is not met. see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html

Comment: sorry I actually confused myself in the description. Caius is correct. I am only checking if an 'insert into' meets the conditions (matching something within other tables) which is suppose to be checked within the trigger. Is there perhaps a snippet or layout you can provide as an example to help me visually.